# How to run a javascript string from database in html with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have a this string:

```
@html = "HELLO <script> alert("this code is from database")</script>"
```

in my file view .erb:

but dont work

is possible run this code with rails from string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad practice, but it is possible

1 with **html_safe**

```
<%- @html.html_safe %>
```

2 with **raw** if your variable could be `nil`

```
raw(@html)
```